# layout not supporting in 7inch android tablet

Tags: android, xml, multiscreen

i have added a layout and it needs to be supported in mutiple screens,i have added layout-xlarge and layout-large and customised each layout but when run the app there is an error >>

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView

I am also not sure if it is the correct way-   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJEaA.jpg)

Comment: Have to added same code to all of the layouts ?

Comment: Yes i have added xlarge for all layout but only added one - large layout as i only needed that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved the issue by adding directories layout-w600dp,values-w600dp and also added layout files to be displayed in the 7inch tablet